# How to call text Watcher when user update any value from edit text

Tags: android

i have button,on button click it create editText with value, value of edit text is depending on count of total edit texts.for example edittext1 = 100, when user create two edit text then the value will be like this edittext1 = 50,edittext2 = 50 and so on.( *value = 100/ total no of edittext)* which i set equally to each edit text.now the problem is when user want to change/update any value from edittext, i want to update value of each edittext according to user's newly entered value.
i want to call textwatcher when value changed by only user,in my case when user click on button it will call. 
thank you.

here is my code

```
 public class StageForm extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stage_form);

    spinnerProjectStage = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAddProjectStage);
    spinnerProjectList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerProjectList);
    stageLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.stageProjectList);
    btnAddMoreStage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddMoreStage);

    btnAddMoreStage.setOnClickListener(this);

    getProjectStage();

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnAddMoreStage) {
        public void addMoreFields () {
            try {
                k++;
                flag = k;
                final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams;
                lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                layout[flag] = new LinearLayout(StageForm.this);
                layout[flag].setLayoutParams(lparams);
                layout[flag].setId(flag);

                txtStageName[flag] = new EditText(StageForm.this);
                txtStageName[flag].setLayoutParams(lparams);
                txtStageName[flag].setHint("stage " + k + "");
                txtStageName[flag].setId(flag);

                txtStagePercent[flag] = new EditText(StageForm.this);
                txtStagePercent[flag].setLayoutParams(lparams);
                txtStagePercent[flag].setHint("percent");
                txtStagePercent[flag].setId(flag);

                txtStagePercent[flag].addTextChangedListener(stagePercentChangeListener);


                if (flag == 0) {
                    txtStagePercent[flag].setText(String.valueOf(totalPercent));
                } else {
                    countEditText = flag + 1;
                    calculatePercentage(countEditText, flag);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            layout[flag].addView(txtStageName[flag]);
            layout[flag].addView(txtStagePercent[flag]);
            stageLinearLayout.addView(layout[flag]);
        }
    }
}

private void calculatePercentage(int countEditText, int flag) {
    k = flag;
    if (flag == 0) {
        //  countEditText = flag;
        lastTextBox = countEditText;
    } else {
        //  countEditText = flag;
        lastTextBox = countEditText - 1;
    }
    result = totalPercent / countEditText;
    convertFloatResult = Math.round(result);
    remainingPercent = totalPercent - (convertFloatResult * countEditText);
    lastTextValue = convertFloatResult + remainingPercent;

    try {
        if (remainingPercent == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= lastTextBox; j++) {
                txtStagePercent[j].setText(String.valueOf(convertFloatResult));
            }
            txtStagePercent[lastTextBox].setText(String.valueOf(lastTextValue));

        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < lastTextBox; j++) {
                txtStagePercent[j].setText(String.valueOf(convertFloatResult));
            }
            txtStagePercent[lastTextBox].setText(String.valueOf(lastTextValue));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private TextWatcher stagePercentChangeListener = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        if (flag == 0) {
        } else {
            String getbeforValue = String.valueOf(s);
            beforeTextChanged = Integer.parseInt(getbeforValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        String getchangedValue = String.valueOf(s);
        afterTextChanged = Integer.parseInt(getchangedValue);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        totalPercent = totalPercent - afterTextChanged;
        countEditText = countEditText - 1;
        calculatePercentage(countEditText, flag);

    }
};
```

}

Comment: editText.addTextChangedListener(this);

Comment: i have already added this line

Comment: As you are creating new Edit Text Fields on Some action, (on button click), then you need to call above line (editText.addTextChangedListener(this) )
for every edit text instance you create, then it will work for all.

for now it will only work for first edit text..

Comment: same thing  i have done already.    txtStagePercent[flag].addTextChangedListener(stagePercentChangeListener);